# Problem in connecting VGA and HDMI/DP simultaneously

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

I am asking for help with a problem with Ubuntu 22.04, on an ONLOGIC Server with:

- i9-13900E processor
- integrated video card intel i915 driver:i915
- integrated video card ASPEED Graphics Family driver:ast

to which I connected an HDMI monitor, a DP monitor, and a VGA monitor.

At power on, Bios screens appear on all three monitors. As soon as Ubuntu is loaded, the monitor with the VGA no longer receives a signal.
I have tried via 'gnome-control-center display' to activate the VGA monitor as well, but it won't let me and shows no error.

Below are the outputs from xrandr:
-[xrandr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWd4n.jpg)
-[xrandr2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eahc7.jpg)

I notice that in xrandr an extra display appears, DP-1-1, which is not connected but appears to be there.
I have already tried disabling and enabling wayland, to no avail.

I am asking for your help to get all three monitors working simultaneously and separately (no mirroring)!

Thank you very much